# Magento 1 New Media Image attribute not showing up in product variable

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I've created an new image attribute, its purpose is to serve as a rollover option. I've implemented my version of it but I've realised on the `catalog/product/list.phtml` the others attribute come up in the data but not the newly created one. Why doesn't it show the new attribute in the data? Is that normal?

[image]

Comment: Have you assign attribute to used "attribute set"? and please reindex after create and assign attribute to attribute set.

Comment: @PrashantValanda yes

Comment: i think you need to load your product using $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); and after you can get your attribute.

Comment: Thats my work around it. But to me its just so weird the fact productCollection wouldn't have this. I as far I know productCollection returns the product model which essential would have the attribute am looking for.

Comment: Have you set the value “YES” to “Used in Product Listing” under storefront Properties while creating the attribute?

Comment: Yes, but that wasn't the problem am going to add my solution, because this has been fixed.

Comment: okay, that's great.